# How do I identify which flutter packages are blocking others from being updated to latest version?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to upgrade my dependencies to the latest possible, but I can't because they are being blocked by one of the packages.

How can I tell which one is causing the issue where others can't be updated? They pretty much all seem to be outdated. Running **flutter pub outdated** gives me the list of my packages where the resolvable and updatable are always the same as my current package.

```html
> flutter pub outdated
Showing outdated packages.
[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name                            Current    Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest  

direct dependencies:
bip39                                   *1.0.3     *1.0.3      *1.0.3      1.0.6
cloud_firestore                         *0.16.0+1  *0.16.0+1   *0.16.0+1   1.0.5
firebase_auth                           *0.20.1    *0.20.1     *0.20.1     1.1.0
firebase_core                           *0.7.0     *0.7.0      *0.7.0      1.0.3
firebase_storage                        *7.0.0     *7.0.0      *7.0.0      8.0.3
flutter_blue                            *0.7.3     *0.7.3      *0.7.3      0.8.0
google_maps_flutter                     *1.2.0     *1.2.0      *1.2.0      2.0.3
http                                    *0.12.2    *0.12.2     *0.12.2     0.13.1
image                                   *2.1.19    *2.1.19     *2.1.19     3.0.2
image_picker                            *0.6.7+22  *0.6.7+22   *0.6.7+22   0.7.4
local_auth                              *0.6.3+4   *0.6.3+4    *0.6.3+4    1.1.4
permission_handler                      *5.1.0+2   *5.1.0+2    *5.1.0+2    6.1.3

transitive dependencies:
archive                                 *2.0.13    *2.0.13     *2.0.13     3.1.2
args                                    *1.6.0     *1.6.0      *1.6.0      2.0.0
bech32                                  *0.1.2     *0.1.2      *0.1.2      0.2.0
bip32                                   *1.0.7     *1.0.7      *1.0.7      1.0.10
bs58check                               *1.0.1     *1.0.1      *1.0.1      1.0.2
cloud_firestore_platform_interface      *3.0.2     *3.0.2      *3.0.2      4.0.1
cloud_firestore_web                     *0.3.0+2   *0.3.0+2    *0.3.0+2    1.0.5
convert                                 *2.1.1     *2.1.1      *2.1.1      3.0.0
crypto                                  *2.1.5     *2.1.5      *2.1.5      3.0.1
firebase_auth_platform_interface        *3.1.0     *3.1.0      *3.1.0      4.1.0
firebase_auth_web                       *0.3.3     *0.3.3      *0.3.3      1.0.6
firebase_core_platform_interface        *3.0.1     *3.0.1      *3.0.1      4.0.0
firebase_core_web                       *0.2.1+3   *0.2.1+3    *0.2.1+3    1.0.2
firebase_storage_platform_interface     *1.0.4     *1.0.4      *1.0.4      2.0.1
firebase_storage_web                    *0.1.1+3   *0.1.1+3    *0.1.1+3    1.0.3
fixnum                                  *0.10.11   *0.10.11    *0.10.11    1.0.0
flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle        *1.0.11    *1.0.11     *1.0.11     2.0.1
google_maps_flutter_platform_interface  *1.2.0     *1.2.0      *1.2.0      2.0.4
hex                                     *0.1.2     *0.1.2      *0.1.2      0.2.0
http_parser                             *3.1.4     *3.1.4      *3.1.4      4.0.0
image_picker_platform_interface         *1.1.6     *1.1.6      *1.1.6      2.1.0
intl                                    *0.16.1    *0.16.1     *0.16.1     0.17.0
permission_handler_platform_interface   *2.0.2     *2.0.2      *2.0.2      3.1.3
petitparser                             *3.1.0     *3.1.0      *3.1.0      4.1.0
plugin_platform_interface               *1.0.3     *1.0.3      *1.0.3      2.0.0
pointycastle                            *1.0.2     *1.0.2      *1.0.2      3.0.1
protobuf                                *1.1.3     *1.1.3      *1.1.3      2.0.0
quiver                                  *2.1.5     *2.1.5      *2.1.5      3.0.1
rxdart                                  *0.24.1    *0.24.1     *0.24.1     0.26.0
source_span                             *1.8.0     *1.8.0      *1.8.0      1.8.1
stream_transform                        *1.2.0     *1.2.0      *1.2.0      2.0.0
uuid                                    *2.2.2     *2.2.2      *2.2.2      3.0.4
xml                                     *4.5.1     *4.5.1      *4.5.1      5.1.0
```

Comment: Any news on this one?

Answer (score 0):

Open pubspec.yaml and try changing the major version of all your (supposedly) upgradable packages.

For example, instead of "^0.20.1", change it into "^0.1.0".
If a third party library prevented the upgrade, flutter would mention it. Then you start looking for alternatives, or you can always roll your own.

If you only use libraries made by flutter.dev or google.com, there should be no problem, since there's small chance of them being abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter pub outdated --verbose` and filter for lines beginning with `SLVR`.  From this you can look at all the containing a package, and the constraints placed on it.  By looking at the ones with an upper limit you can find the limiting dependency.